# Efficient method for logging time series data in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to log several items in .csv format on each update. Previously I have done this in two different ways:

1. Opening and appending a file and then closing it on each update.
2. Storing several samples and periodically logging them in batch.

Both methods achieved what I wanted, but I'm wondering if there are efficiency concerns with either of them.

Should I use some other method entirely?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil: https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended to use logging stable / reliable libraries like NLog or log4net

Link specific to CSV layout setting if using NLog: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/CsvLayout

Provides flexibility for formatting. Efficiency is something you need to measure based on comparison test runs. Plus bring options of archiving log files based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

another approach might be using a data aquisition framework like "LabStreamingLayer". You will find a tiny implementation on my [github account](https://github.com/xfleckx/LSL4Unity).

I know the question is quite dated but LSL is a cool thing and it's worth a try! 
This implementation is still under development but should work out of the box.

[EDIT] You're absolut right. Sorry for the fast shoot... So here is the more comprehensive answer:

The LabStreamingLayer (LSL) framework is a data aquisition framework for high resolution time series. Primary used for stream EEG (Brainsignals... :)) data through the network to save and analyze them. It brings time synchronisation over the network so data streams could be combined for further analysis. 
For example, I'm using the framework to aquire orientation and position data of a object in 3D which will be later correlated to EEG data.

To use the framework, you need to include the C# api (which is actually only the LSL.cs file) and the liblsl.dll into your c# project and than you will be able to push data to LSL with only a couple lines of code.

```
using LSL;

public class LSLOutlet : MonoBehaviour
{
private liblsl.StreamOutlet outlet;
private liblsl.StreamInfo streamInfo;
private float[] currentSample;

public string StreamName = "Unity.ExampleStream";
public string StreamType = "Unity.Random01f";
public int ChannelCount = 4;

void Start()
{
    currentSample = new float[ChannelCount];

    streamInfo = new liblsl.StreamInfo(StreamName, StreamType, ChannelCount, Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    outlet = new liblsl.StreamOutlet(streamInfo);
}

public void FixedUpdate()
{ 
    currentSample[0] = Random.value;
    currentSample[1] = Random.value;
    currentSample[2] = Random.value;
    currentSample[3] = Random.value; 
    outlet.push_sample(currentSample);
}
}
```

`outlet.push_sample(currentSample)` will automaticaly add a timestamp to the sample set. Regarding to Unity's Fixed Update Method to time between two samples should be more or less appStartTime + tn -1 + Time.fixedDeltaTime.

On the other side you need an app which implements:

```
public class LSLInlet : MonoBehaviour {

liblsl.StreamInfo[] results;
liblsl.StreamInlet inlet;

int expectedChannels = 0;

void Start () {

    // wait until the expected stream shows up
    results = liblsl.resolve_stream("type", "Unity.Random01f");
    // open an inlet and print some interesting info about the stream (meta-data, etc.)
    inlet = new liblsl.StreamInlet(results[0]);

    expectedChannels = inlet.info().channel_count();

    Debug.Log(inlet.info().as_xml());
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // read samples
    float[] sample = new float[expectedChannels];

    while (inlet.samples_available() > 0)
    {
        inlet.pull_sample(sample);

        foreach (float f in sample)
            Debug.Log(string.Format("\t{0}", f));

    }
}

}
```

so you will get a time series. You will be able to save the data by your self or could use the [LabRecorder](https://github.com/sccn/labstreaminglayer/tree/master/Apps/LabRecorder) - which saves the stream in a simple xml based file. See the Readme file for more infos.

For more examples please see the examples in the SDK which is linked from in the Readme of the LSL4Unity repository. (Sorry regarding to my low reputation I cannot link the stuff directly).

So, I hope that might help a bit... :) Please consider the documentation of LSL (github wiki etc.) The whole thing is well documented!

Comment: Please add some more details to your answer, *how* would you use it? Can you provide with an example? Just a link is usually not very helpful.